# How can I display a Google map with Search API Views and Search API DB

Tags: google-maps, search, views

I am using Search API with Search API DB, and Facets, with Search Views.  I want to display a map to plot the results from the search.  Is this possible?  I have looked everywhere and can't seem to figure it out.

My nodes currently use geofield for the individual node pages.

Comment: did you try this, https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations

Comment: I did, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried these two modules?
https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap
https://www.drupal.org/project/location

With these two modules, you can create google maps and put your location data into a referenced google map.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: any error message?

Comment: It's because I don't have something configured right I think.  At this point, I think I'm going to add the lat/lng vals to the Drupal JS object, and gather them up and plot them with Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write your own field.tpl file for displaying that field and see how to display google map based on geofield values take a [display google maps using Geolocation values](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation).

Your tpl file will be named **views-view-field--{field_name}.tpl.php** be in the adefault theme folder you could check:
 **views -> advanced -> Theming information** and rescan templates button.

Copy the file **views-view-field.tpl.php** and read its docs for variables available.